# Circular Inclusion with Templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, linker

The following code compiles perfectly:

```
// MyFile.h

#ifndef MYFILE_H_INCLUDED
#define MYFILE_H_INCLUDED

template <typename Datatype>
class MyClass
{
    public:
    void MyMethod();
}

#include "MyFile.cpp"

#endif
```

```
// MyFile.cpp

#ifndef MYFILE_CPP_INCLUDED
#define MYFILE_CPP_INCLUDED

#include "MyFile.h"

template <typename Datatype>
void MyClass<Datatype>::MyMethod()
{
    // ...
}

#endif
```

The definitions of other methods and functions can be separated from the declarations in the same manner.  Are there any downsides to using this approach?  Can this behavior be relied upon?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @GMan Is `.tpp` the "standard" file extension for this sort of thing, or could it just be anything that won't be compiled?

Comment: Standard is a bit strong of a term. Relatively common would be a better description.

Comment: @Itc Just separating template definitions from declarations.  I'm doing this for organization, consistency, and because Xcode only seems to notice changes in my header files when I explicitly save them.  (It should do this automatically before building.)

Comment: You can set it the preferences of XCode to save all modified files when a build is started (this will then pick up your changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the `MyFile.tpp` (I renamed it from .cpp), then you don't need to include the `MyFile.h`. `#include`ing a file is like exactly copying it's content into the file where it's included. Other from that, it's a common practice to organize the headers a bit. (Though you don't need the include-guards in the `MyFile.tpp`, because it should only ever be included from another header directly (like GMan says).)

Answer (score 6):

- Rename the file "MyFile.cpp" to "MyFile.tpp".
- Remove the include guards from "MyFile.tpp"
- Change the include in "MyFile.h" so it is "MyFile.tpp"
- Remove the the include inside "MyFile.tpp"

Note: Because the file is a *.tpp file (not *.cpp) it should not be included by other build system operations. If you have added it manually remove it.

Make sure the only place that includes <X>.tpp is the last line in <X>.h