# Syntax Highlighting in Arbitrary File Types

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks for a project that uses templated classes, and [I'm separating the implementation from the declaration with `.tpp` files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467785/circular-inclusion-with-templates)  However, Code::Blocks doesn't recognize that `.tpp` is a C++ file, so syntax highlighting does not work.  How can I add the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this site can help you: [http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_custom_lexer_for_Code::Blocks_editor](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_custom_lexer_for_Code%3a%3aBlocks_editor)

Comment: Indeed, it did.  I added `*.tpp` to the appropriate XML file and it is now working perfectly.  Thanks!